# Do You Put a Break after the Last case in a Switch?

Tags: coding-standards

The [Arduino Switch Case Reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/switchcase/) has a switch structure written two different ways:

First in the Syntax as:

```
switch (var) {
  case label1:
    // statements
    break;
  case label2:
    // statements
    break;
  default:
    // statements
}
```

and then in the Example code as:

```
  switch (var) {
    case 1:
      //do something when var equals 1
      break;
    case 2:
      //do something when var equals 2
      break;
    default:
      // if nothing else matches, do the default
      // default is optional
      break;
  }
```

Is there any reason to (or not to) add a `break;` in the `default:` case? Does the need for 'break;' change if the final case is not `default:`?

Comment: This isn't an Arduino specific question and it was [already answered on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3003308).

Comment: `break` is an exit command, since the loop is exiting anyway, you do not need it ..... you should use it though because you may cut/paste code, or add another `case` statement after the last `case` statement, and also to form a habit to use it in `case` statements in general

Comment: I'd like to argue that this is Arduino specific because not all C++ rules apply to an Arduino. For example, the lack of an exception system prevents Try and catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you don't have to.

Should you? That's up to you.

I do. That's because it's then simple to add another `case` at the end of the structure in the future if you want, and you don't have to remember to add the `break` to the existing last case.